# Adding Additional Coordination Queue Managers in IBM MQ Explorer

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

Once one has a coordination queue manager in the "Managed File Transfer" folder of the IBM MQ Explorer (with the FTE add-on of course), how is it that one adds additional Coordination Queue managers?  I don't see an "Add Coordiation Qmgr" option from the Managed File Transfer folder ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so following the resolution of a PMR, we find that my implementation of the FTE plugin for MQ explorer at v 7.0.1.2, was such that it precluded the detection of additional coordination queue managers.  I deployed the v7.5 version, and EVERYTHING works fine now. Case closed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a coordination queue manager using fteSetupCoordination command from command line.

```
fteSetupCoordination.cmd -coordinationQMgr QM_COORD2 -coordinationQMgrHost localhost -coordinationQMgrPort 3099 -coordinationQMgrChannel MQSVRCHN
```

This command will create a .mqsc file under config directory. That mqsc file must be run against the new coordination queue manager. For example:

```
runmqsc QM_COORD2 < C:\MQFTE\IBM\WMQFTE\config\QM_COORD2\QM_COORD2.mqsc
```

Start MQ Explorer, you will see `QM_COORD2` as another coordination queue manager under `Managed File Transfer` node. **Note that there can be only one coordination queue manager active at any point.** Hence `QM_COORD2` queue manager will be shown as inactive. You will need to disconnect the active coordination queue manager and then make the `QM_COORD2` active. To make it active, just right click on the `QM_COORD2` and click on `Connect` short menu.

Comment: Thanks ... I had previously created the coordination qmgr, and ran the setup accordingly/runmqsc.  However, my explorer session, to which I can connect (as an administrator) to either my original coordination qmgr (which does show up), or the new queue manager, still only sees the original coordination queue manager.  I can disconnect that one, but I do not have an entry for the NEW one.  So I have no way to activate it by right clicking on anything...?

Comment: I did a restart of MQ Explorer to get the second cooridnation queue manager to appear. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes.  No luck ... it's just not there.  Perhaps I didn't mention that the other Coord. QM is NOT on the same server as the one that does show up in the MFT folder.  So I am using an admin connection to a different queue manager on a totally different server from before.  The mystifying part of this is that I have no idea how the explorer picked up the first one we had actually.  I'll log a PMR I think.